# Build file path in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm new to c++ and want to read a csv file and print out the number of lines.

The directory of the file is passed as commandline argument and the file name is given. The following line should build the path to the csv:

```
//argv[1] = C:\Users\me\source\repos\sol1\proj1\bin\x64\Debug\191003-070100\
string verpfad = argv[1] + std::string("veraenderungen.csv");

//verpfad shows as: C:\Users\me\source\repos\sol1\proj1\bin\x64\Debug\191003-070100 in the console
```

Next, i tried to put the backslash in front of the file name and remove it from the commandline argument:

```
//argv[1] = C:\Users\me\source\repos\sol1\proj1\bin\x64\Debug\191003-070100
string verpfad = argv[1] + std::string("\\veraenderungen.csv");
//verpfad shows as: C:\Users\me\source\repos\sol1\proj1\bin\x64\Debug\191003-070100 in the console
```

Next i tried

```
//argv[1] = C:\Users\me\source\repos\sol1\proj1\bin\x64\Debug\191003-070100
string verpfad = argv[1] + '\\' + std::string("veraenderungen.csv");
//verpfad shows as: veraenderungen.csv in the console
```

How can I fix this?

For completeness the whole code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

//meine includes
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // this line 
    string verpfad = argv[1] + std::string("veraenderungen.csv");


    ifstream ver(verpfad);

    if (!ver.is_open()) std::cout << "Datei " << verpfad << "kann nicht geöffnet werden" << '\n';

    //Anzahl der Zeilen in der Datei
    std::count(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ver), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), '\n');

    ver.close();

    std::cout << "Pfad ist: ";
    std::cout << argv[1] <<  std::endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like it works fine with Visual Studio 2019 in debug mode when I have `"C:\test\frank\\"` set in the Properties for debug mode command line arguments. However with only a single \\ at the end before the `"` the backslash acts as an escape character for the `"`. It also works for me if I do not use a trailing backslash in the command line arguments and put the backslash in the string constant as in `string verpfad = argv[1] + std::string("\\veraenderungen.csv");` What do you mean by "in the console"?

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2017, but I don't think that matters. I got it working with `string verpfad = std::string(argv[1]) + "\\veraenderungen.csv";`, which seems an easy solution to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Do this:

```
string verpfad = std::string(argv[1]) + '\\' + "veraenderungen.csv";
```

And that's it.

The problem is (unfortunately) related to pointers and implicit casting and backwards-compatibility with C and operator associativity and some other technicalities in the C++ language.

You see, `argv[1]` is *not* a "string" (i.e. `std::string`) but merely a pointer to a NUL-terminated array of characters. However, applying the `+` to a `char *` on the left and a `std::string` on the right (i.e. `argv[1] + std::string("...")`) is legal and it does a *string concatenation*, which is what you want here.

But then you go and put a single character between them (which should be of the type `char`, but quite often, it is an `int`) which changes the evaluation of the result of the `+` operation. Now that you are adding three things together, the first add is done first, which is between a pointer and an integer, and its result is far from string concatenation.

The correct way (well, one correct way) is to make the first thing on that line (`argv[1]`) into a `std::string`. The type `std::string` can concatenate characters and pointer to NUL-terminated arrays of characters and some other things to itself using the `+` operator, and the result of those operations are all `std::string`s again, and when there are multiple `+` operators in the same expression they are evaluated from left-to-right... so you'll be fine!

One more thing to remember: contrary to some other languages, adding numbers to a `std::string` won't work. You can use the `std::to_string(x)` to turn numbers into strings.

Comment: I am curious as to your explanation for the first two cases which the OP claims did not work correctly either.

Comment: I didn't get the impression that the first two cases didn't work for the OP; merely that they were the original versions of the code and they OP wanted more.

Comment: I'm going by the comments beneath each of the sample lines of code in which the OP writes what was printed to the console however it seemed to work for me in Visual Studio 2019. And if I use parenthesis, this works: `string verpfad = argv[1] + ('\\' + std::string("veraenderungen.csv"));`